# Php Multiple Instance Upload Files at once on submit with Process On Second Page With Progress Bar

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, progress-bar

Sorry for my English, I had to use Google Translator

I have a form, in this form i have several input upload files.

What I'm trying to do is send the arquives at once to the next page. When its happen it darkens the page and shows a progress bar where it sends all files. Once you do it finishes recording in the database.

**The files uploads is multiple instances**

Found I multiple file uploads but no causes that I am wanting to do and do not know what I can do to get this result.

I can't use **XMLHttpRequest** but i can use **APC**

I do check the size and types of archives (PDF, JPG, ZIP)

I have an image that explains itself, see the link

[Picture](http://www3.mackenzie.com.br/pos_graduacao/uploads/foto/up.jpg)

Comment: There are many ready solutions for this, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129816/2199981

Comment: I know there are several solutions, but none attends what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

Beside the fact that you cant use XMLHttpRequest, any ajax solution can't be used. But in my eyes this works only with ajax.

I recommend you to check out [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). There are several events fired on upload start and while uploading the file(s). Just take a look to the [documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)! Also you can upload multiple files at once, without having several inputs for file uploading.

You can make on upload start (once, just set a var on upload start of the first file to true or something else, what indicates, that the upload has started) show a overlay-div with HTML-elements that simulate a progressbar. This progressbar can be updated by javascript while uploading. Uploadify should give you all information about the files and amount of bytes.

The upload and database part is handled by a php-file which can be specified by you.

Comment: I tried using the uplodify but I have to have multiple file inputs separate for each is for a purpose